# Applying pandas styler to format dataframe header in latex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am trying to get the `latex` file for the following table/dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*5,
                          index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", periods=10),
                          columns=["Tokyo", "Beijing"])

df.index.names = ['date']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

For styling the headers, I try to use `apply_index` as shown in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html) as below:

```
def header_custom(v):
    return f"background-color: blue; color:black; font-weight:bold;"

styler = df.style.apply_index(header_custom,axis="columns")

with open('temp.tex','w') as file: 
    file.write(styler.to_latex(hrules=True,convert_css=True,column_format="p{30mm}|m|m|M|", multirow_align="c",multicol_align="c",clines='all;data'))
```

The code shows an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'` which I don't understand.
It is not related to the `to_latex()` attributes as even removing all of them keeps the same error. Anyone knows how to format the headers using the styler?

Comment: that function you have defined works elementwise, you should use `map_index` formerly `applymap_index`. The alternative `apply_index` operates on series or arrays, not individual elements and requires a sequence as the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution (`* len(v)` was missing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*5,
                          index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", periods=10),
                          columns=["Tokyo", "Beijing"])

df.index.names = ['date']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

def header_custom(v):
    return ['background-color: blue; color:black; font-weight:bold;'] * len(v)

styler = df.style.apply_index(header_custom,axis="columns")

with open('temp.tex','w') as file: 
    file.write(styler.to_latex(hrules=True,convert_css=True,column_format="p{30mm}|m|m|M|", multirow_align="c",multicol_align="c",clines='all;data'))
```

Output:

The `tex` file:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{30mm}|m|m|M|}
\toprule
 & {\cellcolor{blue}} \color{black} \bfseries date & {\cellcolor{blue}} \color{black} \bfseries Tokyo & {\cellcolor{blue}} \color{black} \bfseries Beijing \\
\midrule
0 & 2021-01-01 00:00:00 & 3.081883 & 3.806137 \\
\cline{1-4}
1 & 2021-01-02 00:00:00 & 2.767482 & 2.179288 \\
\cline{1-4}
2 & 2021-01-03 00:00:00 & 2.895136 & 4.780432 \\
\cline{1-4}
3 & 2021-01-04 00:00:00 & 4.977341 & 4.668665 \\
\cline{1-4}
4 & 2021-01-05 00:00:00 & 2.310986 & 2.288097 \\
\cline{1-4}
5 & 2021-01-06 00:00:00 & 0.045837 & 0.096759 \\
\cline{1-4}
6 & 2021-01-07 00:00:00 & 4.482428 & 0.306380 \\
\cline{1-4}
7 & 2021-01-08 00:00:00 & 1.123099 & 3.476060 \\
\cline{1-4}
8 & 2021-01-09 00:00:00 & 4.720301 & 3.372799 \\
\cline{1-4}
9 & 2021-01-10 00:00:00 & 3.367175 & 2.213347 \\
\cline{1-4}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error with this of AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns

Comment: I have just tested it, and everything went fine, @user3507584. I guess you are not using the last `pandas` version.

Comment: I have added the resulting `tex` file to my answer, @user3507584.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas==1.5.3`, I was able to achieve the same result as PaulS with the `np.where` approach which one of the examples of the official documentation is using, specifying a condition which is always `True`. Can you tell us which version of Pandas you are using?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*5,
                          index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", periods=10),
                          columns=["Tokyo", "Beijing"])

df.index.names = ['date']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

def color_b(s):

    formatting_condition = np.where(
        s == s, 
        f"background-color: blue; color:black; font-weight:bold;",
        ""
    )
    return formatting_condition

styler = df.style.apply_index(color_b, axis="columns")  

print(styler.to_latex(
    hrules=True,
    convert_css=True,
    column_format="p{30mm}|m|m|M|",
    multirow_align="c",
    multicol_align="c",
    clines='all;data'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is element wise:

```py
def header_custom(v):
    return f"background-color: blue; color:black; font-weight:bold;"
```

You should use this with `styler.map_index` (formerly `applymap_index`).

The documentation describes the different between the different methods:

- apply operates sequence wise on arrays and requires a func with array return.
- map (applymap) operates element wise and requires a func with a single value return.